# npm publish: FATAL ERROR: JS Allocation failed - process out of memory

Tags: node.js, npm, v8

Here is the result of my npm publish attempts:

```
Fatal error in ../deps/v8/src/handles.h, line 48
CHECK(location_ != NULL) failed


==== C stack trace ===============================

 1: V8_Fatal
 2: v8::String::NewExternal(v8::Isolate*, v8::String::ExternalAsciiStringResource*)
 3: node::ExternString<v8::String::ExternalAsciiStringResource, char>::New(v8::Isolate*, char const*, unsigned long)
 4: node::StringBytes::Encode(v8::Isolate*, char const*, unsigned long, node::encoding)
 5: void node::Buffer::StringSlice<(node::encoding)2>(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&)
 6: v8::internal::FunctionCallbackArguments::Call(void (*)(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&))
 7: ??
 8: ??
Instruction non permise (core dumped)
```

I am trying to publish/update this [repository](https://github.com/B2F/Succss) of mine from alpha to the first stable release.

I tried with the -dd option, which outputs:

```
npm publish --dd
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm verb cli [ 'node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'publish', '--dd' ]
npm info using npm@2.5.1
npm info using node@v0.12.0
npm verb publish [ '.' ]
npm verb cache add spec .
npm verb addLocalDirectory /home/zen/.npm/succss/1.0.0/package.tgz not in flight; packing
npm verb tar pack [ '/home/zen/.npm/succss/1.0.0/package.tgz',
npm verb tar pack   '/home/zen/Projets/Informatique/OpenSource/github/Succss' ]
npm verb tarball /home/zen/.npm/succss/1.0.0/package.tgz
npm verb folder /home/zen/Projets/Informatique/OpenSource/github/Succss
npm info prepublish succss@1.0.0
npm verb addLocalTarball adding from inside cache /home/zen/.npm/succss/1.0.0/package.tgz
npm verb afterAdd /home/zen/.npm/succss/1.0.0/package/package.json not in flight; writing
npm verb afterAdd /home/zen/.npm/succss/1.0.0/package/package.json written
npm verb publish registryBase https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

I also updated node and tried a date buffer as suggested [here](https://github.com/iojs/io.js/issues/649). Right now I can't figure what to do next to fix the problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe npm publish defaults to the latest tag. I don't see a release in your   Github repo - though it looks like you might have one locally? https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/publish

Comment: Indeed i forgot to push the tag, however it did not fix the problem, I even tried npm publish --tags, but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of the [official documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/developers), I wasn't aware that when one publishes a package, it is made of the local directory not the actual repository. I had a large amount of untracked files hence the "out of memory" error. When I moved away the largest directories it fixed the problem... However the proper solution is to use either a .gitignore, .npmignore or both.

Thanks to [npm maintainer Smikes](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/7405#issuecomment-75252713) for the hints.